# How do I get statistics on Azure Devops usage?

Tags: azure-devops

I am currently administering a project on DevOps and wish to verify how many users are using the platform actively.

I want the following information -

```
        1. Unique visitors per month
        2. All visits per month
        3. All visits by roles
```

Comment: You wont' be able to use Azure Devops to get this information as it is a service that aids you in building and deploying apps, not monitoring them. Try [Azure Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/overview) instead.

Comment: @PeterBons You misunderstood the question. It's a question about how to monitor usage of Azure DevOps, not about how to monitor applications.

Comment: @DanielMann That's indeed correct! I wish to monitor the users of DevOps itself.

Comment: Can I know how'e the status of this? Please consider to accept one of below answer if you it would help to others:-) Or free to comment so that we could help you further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best you're going to be able to get is from the usage page (https://dev.azure.com/your_organization/_settings/usage) or audit [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/audit/audit%20log/query?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1). It doesn't include everything you want, but you can probably play with the data once you have it to aggregate it into a format that's more to your liking and extract some of the information you're after.

Answer (score 1):

Based on my opinion, all of those what you want could be achieved by [audit log](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/azure-devops-auditing?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page).

Beside the api that Daniel mentioned, we offered a direct **download** button to download those data. Just select the time period and download them with `CSV`/`JSON` format:

[image]

Here, I suggest you download with **CSV** because it is convenient to apply data filter in it.

> Unique visitors per month

This could be get from the last row: `ActorDisplayName`.

[image]

> All visits by roles

This can be achieved by combined with Users list files. In users page, we also offered a button to download user lists as `.csv` file.

[image]

Just combine the data of `auditlog.csv` and `users.csv`, then you will get the statistics on visiting by roles.

> All visits per month

Not sure what the exactly visit you mentioned. But I think you could get most of you want from auditlog.csv, because we stored the `access ip`, `user agent`, and `detailed operations`.

---

You may think above is not friendly for viewing. So I recommend analyze those statics with Power BI. It can help create `histograms`, `pie charts` or `line charts` and etc, which are very awesome to analyze the data.